# Remove quotes from array to act as a function(variable)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I get an array from a JSON object. Then I want to iterate over that array because they are function names, and I want them to run.

The following will work if I manually do it.

```
var view_functions = [
    header,
    footer
];

for (i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {

    view_functions[i]();             
}
```

But the view_functions variable is supposed to come from the JSON, and not done manually. The JSON part looks like the following, which is an array.

```
"functions" : ["header","footer"]
```

So when I grab the JSON it is an array with quotes around it. How do I make this like the working view_functions var without quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: `"functions" : ["header,footer"]` or `"functions" : ["header", "footer"]`? Is that a typo?

Comment: whichever way your array is supposed to go, get a substring for each element, and do `eval(element).apply()` https://jsfiddle.net/mjsvLobL/

Comment: eval = evil (only difference one letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends: if the functions are in the global scope you can do:

```
window[view_functions[i]]();
```

Remember that all globally defined functions are in fact methods of the global window object. So they can be accessed by using bracket notation `window[...]`. So to avoid using `eval` you can use the bracket notation.

If they are a method of an object you can replace `window` with the object.

It would be a good idea to check if the function exists:

```
Object.prototype.toString(window[view_functions[i]]) === "[object Function]"
```

```js
var funcObj = JSON.parse("{\"functions\" : [\"header\" , \"footer\"]}");

header = function() {
  console.log("test header");
}

footer = function() {
  console.log("test footer");
}

for (var i = 0; i < funcObj.functions.length; i++) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(window[funcObj.functions[i]]) === "[object Function]") {
    window[funcObj.functions[i]]();
  }
};
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window[view_functions[i]] is not a function

Comment: ok so after fixing the typo error, this works... but I feel it should work otherwise.

Comment: Of course it works manually without quotes, because they are function references, but JSON returns them as strings!

Comment: So can we change them to functional references without using window?

Comment: No that would be impossible without using `eval` and we want to avoid that last one!

Comment: Okay I fully understand now. Thank you, this is correct.

Comment: *Remember that all functions are in fact methods of the global window object.* Uh, no that's not true at all. A nested function is not a method of the global `window` object.

Comment: Also, `Object.prototype.toString.call(window[funcObj.functions[i]]) === "[object Function]"` can be replaced with simply: `typeof [[scopeObject]][funcObj.functions[i] === "function"`, where `[[scopeObject]]` is whatever object the functions are in the scope of (it certainly doesn't have to be `window`).

Comment: @scottmarcus, the word globally was not added. You are right of course.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
    var view_functions = you_json_obj.functions; // ["header", "footer"]

    for (let fn of view_functions) {

        window[fn]();             
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no such thing as a JSON "object". JSON is a string format.

If you store your functions in a "dummy" object (just for scope), you can then access property names that match the names in the array.

```js
var view_functions = { "functions" : ["header" , "footer"] };

var dummy = {
 header: function(){ console.log("header"); },
 footer: function(){ console.log("footer"); }
};

// Loop over the strings in the array and invoke the function
// with the matching key in the dummy object:
view_functions.functions.forEach(function(f){
 dummy[f]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and access to the functions that are in the [Global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) using the keyword `window` or `this`.

Code example using `this[fn]()`:

```js
function header () {
  console.log("function header");
}

function footer () {
  console.log("function footer");
}

const view_functions = { 
  "functions": ["header" , "footer"] 
};

view_functions.functions.forEach(fn => this[fn]());
```